# ES6: Accessing to class'es 'this' from inner local function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

In below example, I need to access `this.methodWhichRequredAnywhere()` inside `functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly()`.

```
class Example(){

    construtor(){

        function functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly(){
             // warning: invalid code
            return this.methodWhichRequredAnywhere + ' complete';
        }

        this.message = functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly();
    }

    methodWhichRequredAnywhere(){
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

Too much explanation about closures in answers to another questions, but I still did not found simple solution to solve above problem.

### Note

I understand that above code architecture is contradicting to OOP. Why I used it?

- I suppose, `functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly()` will be utilized after constructor will be executed. Will `methodWhichRequredAnywhere` be?
- I need to group come declarations in my real class. So `functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly()` goes directly below some declarations where it used.

Comment: Turn `functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly` into an arrow function

Comment: @CertainPerformance, `functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly = () => { /* ... */}` - this way? `functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly () => { /* ... */}` will be invalid...

Comment: Yep, though you would put `const` in front of it so as not to implicitly create a global variable, I'm sure there are many posts about this sort of thing

Comment: @CertainPerformance - `many posts` - countless, on a daily basis :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function and explicitly set its `this` value to the value you want. You can do that with `.call`:

```
this.message = functionWhichRequiredInConstructorOnly.call(this);
```

Or define the function as an arrow function as suggested in the comments. Arrow functions don't have their own `this` binding but resolve it lexically just like any other variable.

Related:

- [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) (though you are not having a callback here)
- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)